# Как получить возвращаемые данные из асинхронных функций

Tags: python, асинхронность

У меня есть несколько sql запросов и для них я сделал аналогичные функции:

```
async def get_from_table1():
    return pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [table1]', conn)
```

// conn - подключение к бд через sqlalchemy

Далее вызываю список функций следующим образом без ошибок и точно асинхронно(проверил по time):

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table1()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table2()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table3()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table4()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table5()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table6())
    )


asyncio.run(main())
```

Однако я не знаю как мне получить данных которые я возращаю. Как можно это сделать? Я новичок в асинхронном программировании. Извините за глупый вопрос.

Comment: asyncio.gather возвращает все данные, просто используйте возвращаемое значение хоть как-нибудь

Comment: У вас в асинхронной функции get_from_table1 вызов pd.read_sql_query как синхронной функции (либо это и есть синхронная функция). Если это асинхронная функция, она должна вызываться с await. Если синхронная, то от того что вы ее в асинхронную функцию обернули она не станет волшебным образом работать асинхронно. Это комментарий к "и точно асинхронно"

Comment: @andreymal да, сработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @insolor тогда можно узнать, что нужно исправить, чтобы эта функция стала асинхронной?

Comment: @Dolya можно попробовать обернуть в asyncio.to_thread, см https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread

Comment: Еще лучше - найти библиотеку, которая умеет делать асинхронные запросы к вашей базе, типа aiopg для postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, благодаря пользователям **andreymal** и **insolor** +- разобрался в данном вопросе. Здесь воспользовался библиотекой **aioodbc** (бд у меня была mssql)

Первым делом я изменил функцию main:

```
async def main():
    res = await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table1()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table2()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table3()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table4()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table5()),
        asyncio.create_task(view_to_pd.get_from_db_table6())
    )
return res
```

Однако теперь мне нужно преобразовать функции get_from_db_table в асинхронные. Т.к. у меня есть библиотека aioodbc, то я буду получать данные списком кортежей, а мне нужно вернуть DataFrame. Мне нужно было написать строчку:

```
await pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

Но она вызывает ошибку. Прошерстив немного интернет, я понял, что нет библиотеки для pandas, следовательно придется использовать костыльную функцию:

```
async def to_df(content, columns):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.array(content), columns=columns)
```

Тогда функции получения данных будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
async def get_from_db_table1():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    conn = await aioodbc.connect(dsn=conn_str, loop=loop)
    crs = await conn.cursor()
    await crs.execute("SELECT * FROM [table1]")
    rows = await crs.fetchall()
    await conn.close()
    res = await asyncio.gather(to_df(rows, columns=columns_table1]))
    return res[0]
```

Итого: на получение данных из 8-ми таблиц синхронным способом у меня ушло 15 секунд, а асинхронным 7 секунд!

Comment: `res = await asyncio.gather(to_df(rows, columns=columns_table1]))` - одну функцию в gather нет смысла оборачивать. Для одной асинхронной функции достаточно было бы написать `return await function()`, а так как создание DataFrame - синхронная операция, то нужно было просто написать `return pd.DataFrame(np.array(rows), columns=columns)`

Comment: Если rows - список, то в np.array не нужно преобразовывать перед созданием датафрейма: `return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)`

Comment: @insolor да, действительно! Скорость работы уменьшилась до 6.5 секунд, а функция to_df оказалась в целом не нужной. А вот по поводу нужно ли преобразовывать в np.array, здесь мне нужно было его использовать, т.к. без него выходила ошибка 'ValueError: Shape of passed values'